# Script error in MDN web extension example

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, eval, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to run the MDB example extension at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension and it always fails with the message:

`Failed to execute beastify content script unexpected token: ':'`

The other message in the console says. `scriptElement:88:13`

I thought the error message comes from the `:` in the line but even removing it still gives the message, so there must be something passed in the string `error.message` that is causing the error.

The whole project is at https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify and the error is from [`choose_beast.js` line 88](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/e1dcb308f29d8c1ada090b25aea9542fa958eea0/beastify/popup/choose_beast.js#L88).

From what I see the `${error.message}` contains some executable string that has a syntax error.

```
function reportExecuteScriptError(error) {
    document.querySelector("#popup-content").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#error-content").classList.remove("hidden");
    console.error(`Failed to execute beastify content script: ${error.message}`);
}
```

Comment: well, couldn't you post an issue on their github? They seem to be somewhat active in handling those? Sometimes it happens that people mistakingly use `:` for `;` semicolon and it gets missed in a review, I know I had that happen to me already ^_^

Comment: When I download directly from Github it works. What I need to know is how to pinpoint the exact syntax error, from whatever the `error.message` string contains if it is the true origin of the error.
I am a Javascript novice. Do you know of a tool that can run through the code and pinpoint where the error might be from a static analysis?